# Group a JSON object with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am sorry if this is a duplicate question. But I couldn't be helped by the other similar questions yet. I have a JSON file like this:

```
[
      {
        age: 25,
        id: 1,
        name: "Iqbal Hussain",
        receivedOn: "2014-10-21",
        resource_uri: "/api/v1/student/1/",
        sex: "M",
        ugPercentage: 79
      },{
        age: 26,
        id: 2,
        name: "Anis Sarkar",
        receivedOn: "2014-10-20",
        resource_uri: "/api/v1/student/2/",
        sex: "M",
        ugPercentage: 67
      },{
        age: 25,
        id: 3,
        name: "Abumutalib Sheikh",
        receivedOn: "2014-10-20",
        resource_uri: "/api/v1/student/3/",
        sex: "M",
        ugPercentage: 59
      },{
        age: 24,
        id: 4,
        name: "Abhijeet Paul",
        receivedOn: "2014-10-21",
        resource_uri: "/api/v1/student/4/",
        sex: "M",
        ugPercentage: 62  
      }
    ]
```

I want it to be converted like this:

```js
[
  {
    receivedOn: "2014-10-21",
    total: 2
  },{
    receivedOn: "2014-10-20",
    total: 2  
  }
]
```

where total is the number of objects having same receivedOn value

Comment: So, what have you tried so far my friend?

Comment: @MikeAnte He is not your friend, Bro... ;)

Comment: Where does `total` come from?

Comment: Come on, you should at least give some info on how you want to make "total".

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/bc8m036t/ :)

Comment: Interesting question but you should have explained that you want to group by `receivedOn` field and calculate count of this agregation.

Comment: check this out 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860382/how-can-i-group-an-array-of-json-objects-by-month

Comment: Look this: [exactly what you need][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860382/how-can-i-group-an-array-of-json-objects-by-month

Comment: @Moobs Total is the number of objects with same receivedOn value. Sorry I forgot to mention this.

Comment: No good luck yet! Can someone just give an answer with the exact code?

Comment: @dfsq Like what? That's my code itself! I don't know how it went there. I am not so much experienced in asking questions in stackoverflow. And yeah, Thanks for understanding what I wanted to ask.

Comment: @iqbal Take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ymofL15d/

Comment: @dfsq Thank you very much. You have just saved my day.

Comment: Please provide some reasons before down voting....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@dfsq gave this answer which did exactly what I wanted.

```js
var data = [{
    age: 25,
    id: 1,
    name: "Iqbal Hussain",
    receivedOn: "2014-10-21",
    resource_uri: "/api/v1/student/1/",
    sex: "M",
    ugPercentage: 79
}, {
    age: 26,
    id: 2,
    name: "Anis Sarkar",
    receivedOn: "2014-10-20",
    resource_uri: "/api/v1/student/2/",
    sex: "M",
    ugPercentage: 67
}, {
    age: 25,
    id: 3,
    name: "Abumutalib Sheikh",
    receivedOn: "2014-10-20",
    resource_uri: "/api/v1/student/3/",
    sex: "M",
    ugPercentage: 59
}, {
    age: 24,
    id: 4,
    name: "Abhijeet Paul",
    receivedOn: "2014-10-21",
    resource_uri: "/api/v1/student/4/",
    sex: "M",
    ugPercentage: 62
}];

var obj = {};
data.forEach(function(el) {
    if (!obj[el.receivedOn]) {
        obj[el.receivedOn] = 0;
    }
    obj[el.receivedOn] += 1;
});

var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    return {receivedOn: key, total: obj[key]};
});

alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```