# Do a count and group by weeks or months

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I have an object array like this:

```
[ { date: '2017-11-17', count: 2 }, { date: '2017-11-16', count: 24 }, { date: '2017-11-15', count: 42 }, { date: '2017-11-14', count: 23 }, { date: '2017-11-13', count: 33 }, { date: '2017-11-12', count: 22 }, { date: '2017-11-11', count: 11 }, { date: '2017-10-04', count: 66 } ]
```

Using the momentJS library and pure javascript only (no lodash _groupBy etc), how can I group the results and add together the 'count' to be like this:

Week Grouping: (Monday is start of week)

```
[ { date: '2017-11-13', count: 104 }, { date: '2017-11-06', count: 22 }, { date: '2017-10-02', count: 66 } ]
```

Month Grouping: (1st of month is start of month)

```
[ { date: '2017-11-01', count: 26 }, { date: '2017-10-01', count: 66 } ]
```

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried something and it's not working? If yes, what's not working? Can you please post what you tried and what the problem is?

Comment: Look into map and reduce function of array prototype. MDN is helpful with that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17861074/8281584,  have you check this link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I group an array of objects by month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860382/how-can-i-group-an-array-of-objects-by-month)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function I wrote. You pass it your array as the first argument, and 'week' or 'month' as the second one.

```
function groupBy(elements, duration) {
  const formatted = elements.map(elem => {
    return { date: moment(elem.date).startOf(duration).format('YYYY-MM-DD'), count: elem.count }
  })

  const dates = formatted.map(elem => elem.date)
  const uniqueDates = dates.filter((date, index) => dates.indexOf(date) === index)

  return uniqueDates.map(date => {
    const count = formatted.filter(elem => elem.date === date).reduce((count, elem) => count + elem.count, 0)
    return { date, count }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code groups by weeks. Get inspired to group by month:

```js
var datas = [ { date: '2017-11-17', count: 2 }, { date: '2017-11-16', count: 24 }, { date: '2017-11-15', count: 42 }, { date: '2017-11-14', count: 23 }, { date: '2017-11-13', count: 33 }, { date: '2017-11-12', count: 22 }, { date: '2017-11-11', count: 11 }, { date: '2017-10-04', count: 66 } ];
var groupedByWeek = datas.reduce((m, o) => {
    var monday = getMonday(new Date(o.date));
    var mondayYMD = monday.toISOString().slice(0,10);
    var found = m.find(e => e.date === mondayYMD);
    if (found) {
        found.count += o.count;
    } else {
        o.date = mondayYMD;
        m.push(o);
    }
    return m;
}, []);

console.log(groupedByWeek);

function getMonday(d) {
    var day = d.getDay();
    var diff = d.getDate() - day + (day === 0 ? -6 : 1);  
    return new Date(d.setDate(diff));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function for grouping with a callback for individual grouping (here for month) and take a hash table for keeping same groups.

```js
function groupBy(array, groupFn) {
    var hash = Object.create(null),
        result = [];

    array.forEach(function (o) {
        var key = groupFn(o);
        if (!hash[key]) {
            hash[key] = { date: key, count: 0 };
            result.push(hash[key]);
        }
        hash[key].count += o.count;
    });
    return result;
}

var data = [{ date: '2017-11-17', count: 2 }, { date: '2017-11-16', count: 24 }, { date: '2017-11-15', count: 42 }, { date: '2017-11-14', count: 23 }, { date: '2017-11-13', count: 33 }, { date: '2017-11-12', count: 22 }, { date: '2017-11-11', count: 11 }, { date: '2017-10-04', count: 66 }],
    month = function (o) { return o.date.slice(0, 7) + '-01'; },
    week = function (o) {
        var d = new Date(o.date),
            day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
            offset = 4 * day;

        d.setTime(Math.floor((d.valueOf() - offset) / 7 / day) * 7 * day + offset);
        return d.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
    };

console.log(groupBy(data, month));
console.log(groupBy(data, week));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to group your data array into groups of month and week using a object lookup.

```js
const data = [ { date: '2017-11-17', count: 2 }, { date: '2017-11-16', count: 24 }, { date: '2017-11-15', count: 42 }, { date: '2017-11-14', count: 23 }, { date: '2017-11-13', count: 33 }, { date: '2017-11-12', count: 22 }, { date: '2017-11-11', count: 11 }, { date: '2017-10-04', count: 66 } ];

var sortedByMonth = data.reduce((res, {date, count}) => {
  let [year, month, day] = date.split('-');
  res[month] ? res[month].count += count : res[month] = { date : year+'-'+month+'-'+'01', count};
  return res;
},{});

console.log(Object.values(sortedByMonth));

var sortedByWeek = data.reduce((res, {date, count}) => {
  var startOfWeek = moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').startOf('week').add(1,'days');
  res[startOfWeek] ? res[startOfWeek].count += count : res[startOfWeek] = {date: moment(startOfWeek).format('YYYY-MM-DD'), count};
  return res;
},{});
console.log(Object.values(sortedByWeek));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```